# clone primefaces components with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, preventdefault

I have a div component to clone that contains primefaces components and that goes like this :

```
<div id="languageBox1">
    <p>
        <h:form>
            <label>Language</label>
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{candidateController.language}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Language" itemValue="language"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItems value="#{candidateController.languages}"
                               var="l" itemLabel="#{l}" itemValue="#{l}"></f:selectItems>
                <p:ajax event="change"
                        update=":formShowResult:candidateList :resultNumberForm"
                        listener="#{candidateController.valueChangeListener}"></p:ajax>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{candidateController.languageLevel}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Level" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItems value="#{candidateController.level}" var="lv"
                               itemLabel="#{lv}" itemValue="#{lv}"></f:selectItems>
                <p:ajax event="change" update=":formShowResult:candidateList"
                        listener="#{candidateController.valueChangeListener}"></p:ajax>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <button id="addLanguage" class="active_grey full">Add</button>
        </h:form>
    </p>
</div>
```

And I've created a script to clone this `div`, that goes like this:

```
$("#addLanguage").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#languageBox1").clone().appendTo("#languageBox2");
});
```

Now my problem is, the cloned selects won't work, I just can't select any option and it won't open any more, I thought the preventdefault instruction made frozen but I'm using it to prevent the button from submitting the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's fix your code. I've modified it like this.

```
<div class="language-container">
    <div class="language-box">
        <p>
            <h:form>
                <label>Language</label>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{candidateController.language}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Language" itemValue="language"></f:selectItem>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{candidateController.languages}"
                        var="l" itemLabel="#{l}" itemValue="#{l}"></f:selectItems>
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                        update=":formShowResult:candidateList :resultNumberForm"
                        listener="#{candidateController.valueChangeListener}"></p:ajax>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{candidateController.languageLevel}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Level" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{candidateController.level}" var="lv"
                        itemLabel="#{lv}" itemValue="#{lv}"></f:selectItems>
                    <p:ajax event="change" update=":formShowResult:candidateList"
                        listener="#{candidateController.valueChangeListener}"></p:ajax>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <button class="addLanguage active_grey full">Add</button>
            </h:form>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I've did is I added a `language-container` as a parent for your language box. Assuming-ly your language box will be your child that will repeat over and over again.

I've removed the ids for convenience sake and I changed it to class. Since we should know the basic rules that ids SHOULD be unique. That's why we'll be using class.

Now we're gonna call a click event handler on every `.addLanguage` has been clicked.

```
$(document).on("click", ".addLanguage", function() {
    $(".language-box:first-child").clone().appendTo(".language-container");    
});
```

What this does is, everytime that `.addLanguage` has been clicked. The Language box class (child box) will be cloned (first child / element) and append to the parent class `.language-container`.

For you to appreciate it, here's a jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/2tuqu2oL/

Comment: oh thank you for your answer, and I am sorry maybe I didn't make my question clear enough, but now I understand my problem , actually what i need is to change new components ids because I figured that's what made them freeze. and thank you angain

Comment: thank you dude for your answer, I think that I am almost there, the cloning part is working, so now I can clone these elements unlimited-ly but the primefaces components are still freezing, I will search more and please, if you find something helpful please let me, I'll do the same if this works.

Comment: actually that was primefaces issue if I change p:selectonemenu to h:selectonemenu the cloning works perfectly, thanks dude ^^

Comment: @safubi, sorry for the late reply. Took a good night sleep. Glad it solved your problem. :)